# Where to call logging.setLoggerClass() in Django

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm using Django 1.3 with the standard Python logging. I've configured it to log errors to a file:

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['logfile'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
```

I also want the username of the currently logged in Django user to be logged. For that I've defined my own formatter with a format that includes "%(username)s" and created my own logging class (named `RequestLogger`) which populates the extra `username` attribute. The only thing left to do is to call:

```
logging.setLoggerClass(RequestLogger)
```

The question is: **where should I call this?** I've tried putting it into `__init__.py` (at project level) and into `settings.py`. Both of those work fine with the Django dev server, but when running in Apache using WSGI I get errors like this in the Apache error log:

```
[error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 842, in emit
[error]     msg = self.format(record)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 719, in format
[error]     return fmt.format(record)
[error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 467, in format
[error]     s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
[error] KeyError: 'username'
[error] Logged from file base.py, line 209
```

This seems to imply that in WSGI the Django logger gets initialised before my `logging.setLoggerClass()` call. (It's definitely getting called, because my own logging works and includes the username).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use a custom logging class, you can use a Filter on your handlers to do this. See [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/configuring-logging-for-web.html), and [this part](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information) of the docs.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, a filter avoids this problem entirely. I didn't realise that filters can modify the log record, but they can.

Answer (score 3):

**Vinay Sajip**'s solution of using a filter avoids this problem entirely, so I'm accepting his answer. The documentation on how to configure a filter using a dictionary is a bit lacking, so I'll put an example here:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'filters': {
        'add_django_request': {
            '()': 'logger.AddDjangoRequestFilter',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'myhandler': {
            ...
            'filters': ['add_django_request'],
        },
    },
```

In case anyone is wondering, it does work with a custom Logger class if you call `setLoggerClass` inside the .wsgi file, before the `import django.core.handlers.wsgi` line (for Apache) and also inside manage.py (for the Django dev server). The filter solution is better, though.